# Count the number of entities with cakephp 3

Tags: count, entity, cakephp-3.0

I want count the number of entities with Cakephp 3.0, so, I read the book, and i found the query 
`$number = $this->Models->find()->where(['variables' => 1])->count();`
But now, how view the number of entities in my view ?

I have :

```
$this->set(compact('number'));
```

Thanks !

Comment: `echo $number;`? You need to be a little more specific as to what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Not $models->number; ?

Comment: Why don't you try it, then you'll see if it works or not (it won't)?

Comment: Thanks, echo $number work ! I was think, $post->number; but no ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just by using this in your view :`<?=$number?>`